# I need to display pdf file from SD Card using iText.jar 5.0.6

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I have make an application in which I want to display pdf of images which is captured by camera.

I am able to capture the image and store it in pdf file. But when I open the pdf to display images,it gives me an error . To display an pdf file I have used the iText.jar 5.0.6.

Answer (score 1):

iText is not a PDF viewer. You should have a look at [IcePDF](http://www.icepdf.org/) instead, although I'm not sure it can be used on Android platforms.